# Deploying webservice using virtualbox sdk 4.0 in glassfish3.1

Tags: java, web-services, exception, glassfish, virtualbox

After plenty of attempts and research I can't figure out where this exception comes from:

```
SEVERE: Exception in thread "Thread-31" 
SEVERE: java.lang.IllegalStateException: WEB9031: WebappClassLoader unable to load resource [vboxwebService_4_0.wsdl], because it has not yet been started, or was already stopped
    at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.findResourceInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2074)
    at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.findResource(WebappClassLoader.java:1034)
    at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.getResource(WebappClassLoader.java:1169)
    at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.getResource(WebappClassLoader.java:1135)
    at org.virtualbox_4_0.PortPool.getPort(VirtualBoxManager.java:105)
    at org.virtualbox_4_0.PortPool.preinit(VirtualBoxManager.java:82)
    at org.virtualbox_4_0.PortPool.access$200(VirtualBoxManager.java:36)
    at org.virtualbox_4_0.PortPool$1.run(VirtualBoxManager.java:62)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

The idea was to create a webservice that uses the virtualbox 4.0 sdk.
I tried this within:
   - eclipse helios service pack2
   - glassfish 3.1

The service contains the vboxjws.jar in WEB-INF/lib now whenever I try to start it upon the server I get the exception from above.

Am I missing something essential that could solve this issue?

Thanks in advance,

Giriel